# use pipe to transform all request body to DTO object without redundant property

Tags: nestjs, pipe, dto, class-transformer

I'm new in NestJs. I want to do a transformation for incoming request to remove redundant property that not declare in DTO file.

I have DTO:

```js
export class UpdateUserDto {
  @Expose() id: string

  @Expose() name: string

  @Expose() address: string

  @Expose() phone: string
}
```

Controller:

```js
@Patch(':id')
async update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateData: UpdateUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
  return await this.userService.update(id, updateData)
}
```

Incoming request body:

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Name test",
  "address": "Address test",
  "phone": "12312312",
  "hahaha": "hihihi" // this property not declare in DTO file will be remove
}
```

I want transfer to

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Name test",
  "address": "Address test",
  "phone": "12312312"
}
```

Can I use Custom Pipe to handle it. Like this:

Controller:

```js
@Patch(':id')
@UsePipes(new RequestTransferPipe(UpdateUserDto))
async update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateData: UpdateUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
  return await this.userService.update(id, updateData)
}
```

I tried to get metatype from ArgumentMetadata but incoming request transfered to empty object. I want to keep property that declared in DTO file and remove others

Answer (score 2):

If **stripping** properties that are not listed in DTO is what you want, then nestjs official documentation cover exactly this particular use case.

You can use nestjs built-in validation pipe to **filter out** any properties not included in DTO. In your main.ts file add new global validation pipe and add **whitelist**:  **true** to validation pipe option

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );
```

above code will automatically remove non-white listed properties ***(those without any decorator in validation-class)***

You can read more in Nestjs official documentation : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use case, you can simply use the built-in NestJS `ValidationPipe` which uses `class-validator` package under the hood

In your `main.ts`, add:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({

  /*
  * when a client tries to include properties not included in your DTO, 
  * the validator will throw an error
  */
  forbidUnknownValues: true,
}))
```

You can read more about `class-validator` here: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator